# Does F# allows class definition in different files?

Tags: f#

I have tried moving my type definition to a different .fs file, I have declared the same namespace in both the files but my code that uses the type won't recognize the type. Does F# allow that ?

Comment: Yes, but F# processes the source files in order so you have to make sure the file that references the class appears after the one containing the definition.

Comment: You mean the class definition file should be alphabetically called something so it appears *before* the file that uses it ?

Comment: It's not alphabetical, if you're using VS you can move files up and down in the list with Alt-Up/Down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, yes this is definitely supported, but there is a requirement (unlike, e.g. C#) that the source file defining your type must be "above" or "before" the source file which consumes it.

So if you have 2 files:

File1.fs

```
namespace Type.Test    
type Person = { Name : string; Age : int }
```

File2.fs

```
namespace Type.Test
module ConsumeType = 
    let richDude : Person = { Name = "Bill"; Age = 58 }
```

then when the compiler is called on the command line, File1.fs need to be passed first, before File2.fs:

```
c:\> fsc.exe -a File1.fs File2.fs
```

If you are in Visual Studio (or some other IDE) to compile, you need to put File1.fs "above" File2.fs:

[image: file order]

As mentioned by @Lee in the comments, you can re-order the files in VS by clicking on them and using Alt-Up / Alt-Down.